# How do I Use ConfigurationBuilder in .net core 3.1 Winforms?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have the following working in a .net core 2.1 aspnet application

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile(path: "appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();
```

When  I attempt something similar with a .net core 3.1 WInforms application I see that SetBasePath and AddJsonFile are not available

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
namespace myapp {

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private SyndicationFeed feed;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder();

        configuration.SetBasePath(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());  // errors here
        configuration.AddJsonFile(path: "appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true); // errors here
        configuration.Build();
    }
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I tried the same code that you have posted. I could able to compile and run the app after adding the following NuGet packages.

> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (Version 3.1.0)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json (Version 3.1.0)

Most probably you are missing these packages in your environment.

Comment: I was missing Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json

Comment: Great!!!, i don't know why VS not made any suggestion for this. thanks a lot.

Comment: You need all three of: 1) Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, for ConfigurationBuilder, 2) Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json, for  AddJsonFile(), *AND* 3) Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions, for SetBasePath()

Answer (score 6):

You extension method SetBasePath is defined in `Config.FileExtensions`.

Can you check if you are missing a reference to:
`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions` package.

For resolving AddJsonFile, need to add a reference to the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` package.